# Issue when trying to execute spark-submit command in git bash

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to run below spark-submit command:

```
./bin/spark-submit --class HelloSpark --master local ./HelloSpark/target/scala-2.12\hellospark_2.12-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I am running it through git bash prompt. When I run the command, it's getting executed but it's neither showing any output nor throwing any error. It's simply going to the next line.

What does this mean? Where can I see the output? Please help..

Comment: please add some code , what do you have inside hellospark jar ?

Comment: you have slashes and backslashes in the same path

Comment: Don't use scala-2.12. Spark supports Scala 2.11.